# Monorepo with Lerna and TypeScript fails to import package by path alias

Tags: typescript, lerna, monorepo

I am trying to setup a TypeScript based monorepo using [Lerna](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna) where I have two packages, *bar* and *foo*. *foo* imports *bar* by path alias and fails doing so.

1. `tree`

```
.
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── packages
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   │   └── index.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── foo
│       ├── lib
│       │   ├── index.d.ts
│       │   └── index.js
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       │   └── index.ts
│       ├── tsconfig.build.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.build.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

2. ./tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

3. ./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@company/bar": [
        "packages/bar"
      ],
      "@company/foo": [
        "packages/foo"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

4. ./lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

5. ./package.json

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "lerna run tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.22.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.63",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

**Package *bar*:**

6. ./packages/bar/src/index.ts

```
export const bar = 'bar';
```

7. ./packages/bar/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@company/bar",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  ...

  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json"
  }
}
```

8. ./packages/bar/tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

9. ./packages/bar/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

**Package *foo*:**

10. ./packages/foo/src/index.ts

```
import { bar } from '@company/bar';

console.log(bar);
```

11. ./packages/foo/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@company/foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  ...

  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json"
  }
}
```

12. ./packages/foo/tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

13. ./packages/foo/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

**Finally:**

Running `npm run tsc` compiles my packages, where *foo* imports *bar*. It gives me the following error:

```
> lerna run tsc

lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info Executing command in 2 packages: "npm run tsc"
lerna info run Ran npm script 'tsc' in '@company/bar' in 2.4s:

> @company/bar@1.0.0 tsc /.../monorepo-lerna/packages/bar
> tsc -p tsconfig.build.json

lerna ERR! npm run tsc exited 2 in '@company/foo'
lerna ERR! npm run tsc stdout:

> @company/foo@1.0.0 tsc /.../monorepo-lerna/packages/foo
> tsc -p tsconfig.build.json

src/index.ts(1,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@company/bar' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The error itself is pretty clear, though I do not know how to fix it (the path aliases inside ./tsconfig.json (3) look fine I guess). Any ideas where my configs are messed up? What point do I miss?

If I change `import { bar } from '@company/bar';` to `import { bar } from '../../bar/src';` everything works fine, however I would like to stick with the first way to import `bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the part that allows you to import the packages as `@company/bar`

```
    "paths": {
      "@company/bar": [
        "packages/bar"
      ],
      "@company/foo": [
        "packages/foo"
      ]
    }
```

This is specified in `./tsconfig.json`.  When you try to compile package `foo` it is using `./packages/foo/tsconfig.build.json` which never includes the root config or specify the paths itself, you probably want to remove the import scheme from the base `tscofig` and add them to the inner package configs:

`./packages/foo/tsconfig.build.json` should incorporate this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@company/bar": [
        "../bar"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and similarly `packages/bar/tsconfig.build.json` should be allowed to import `@company/foo` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I spent another day getting everything up and running, but unfortunately some errors (mainly regarding more complicated stuff like the integration of nodemon and ts-node-dev) remained. Though, I got the configs all done. Finally I moved to Yarn using its concept of [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces) in cmobination with Lerna. Works like a charm :)